# Observing changes in visibleCells array of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, key-value-observing

I would like to know when the count of `visibleCells` property of `UICollectionView` changes.
I know that I can observe objects that inherit from `NSObject` as long as the property I want to observe is `dynamic`. For example:

```
let view = UIView()
view.observe(\.isHidden, options: .new) { view, change in
  print(change.newValue)
}
```

How can I observe `visibleCells` of `UICollectionView` in a similar manner?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so sure that KVO is going to help you here.  However collectionView does  have the delegate methods [collectionView(*:willDisplay:forItemAt:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview) and [collectionView(:didEndDisplaying:forItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618006-collectionview) which you can use to infer changes in the visible cells.  You could also check in [scrollViewDidScroll(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the visible cell rendering in willDisplay by
For cell in collectionview.visiblecells {
}